# How do I style ShadowDOM elements using external CSS in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, shadow-dom

I'm trying to build a custom HTML element. The problem is that I'm not able to apply styles to the Shadow DOM elements provided using external CSS. The code is working in Chrome but not in Firefox.

```js
var proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);

proto.createdCallback = function() {

    console.log('Element creation started...');

    var inputTextElement = document.createElement('input');
    inputTextElement.type = 'text';
    inputTextElement.className = 'simpleElem';

    // Shadow DOM root
    var shadowRoot = this.createShadowRoot();

    shadowRoot.appendChild(inputTextElement);

    console.log('Element creation ended...');

};

var SimpleElement = document.registerElement('simple-element', { prototype: proto });
```

```css
simple-element {
}

simple-element::shadow  .simpleElem {
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 180px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML5 | Custom Elements</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="simple-elem.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="simple-elem.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <simple-element></simple-element>
    </body>
</html>
```

Not able to figure out what is wrong with Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Shadow DOM in general has been supported in Firefox for a while now (invalidating the two other answers), with Firefox 72 you can now target custom/Shadow DOM elements via the `part` attribute and `::part()` pseudo-element, respectively:

```js
//this JS boilerplate adapted from MDN
let template = document.getElementById("simple-element");
globalThis.customElements.define(template.id, class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content);
  }
});
```

```css
simple-element::part(shadow) {
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 180px;
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<template id="simple-element">
    <div part="shadow">Hi</div>
</template>

<simple-element></simple-element>
```

Obviously this code looks a lot different from what your question code looks like because the Shadow DOM spec/implementations have changed quite a lot since 2014.

Answer (score 2):

**Update: FF Shadow DOM support has [arrived](https://caniuse.com/#feat=shadowdomv1).**

Firefox has no Shadow DOM support yet, see [CanIUse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=shadowdom). I recommend sticking to Chrome. 
EDIT: FF Nightly [has some support](http://soledadpenades.com/2014/01/02/shadow-dom-in-firefox/), it can be enabled manually.

Answer (score 2):

As noted by [Gábor Imre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25366583/1431146), Shadow DOM is not enabled by default in Firefox because it is still under development. You can, however, use a [polyfill](http://www.polymer-project.org/platform/shadow-dom.html) to get pretty good Shadow DOM behavior in all browsers that don't support it.. If you do, you'll then need to use [`polyfill-next-selector`](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/styling.html#at-polyfill) to obtain the behavior you want.